# Doubt in finding volume and setting up the limits?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I am currently confused in how to find volume enclosed between two surfaces $z_1=f_1(x,y),z_2(x,y)=f_2(x,y)$

After going through some online resources, I thought the general way of doing this is:

$\iint_{D} (z_2-z_1) dxdy$ where it will be $(z_2-z_1)$ or $(z_1-z_2)$ depending on the surfaces.

$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:  f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)$ (eliminating $z$ from the two equation)$\}$

However I got stuck while solving the problem .

> Find the volume between the surfaces $x+y+2z=2,2x+y+z=4$
> in the first octent.

I could figure out that it would be of the form

$$\iint _D \left\{(4-(2x+y))-\frac{(2-(x+y))}{2}\right\}\,dxdy$$

However how do I figure out $D$?

Should I take the projection of the two surfaces on the $xy$ plane and then find out the limits as we did in double integration?

Or should I equate the two surfaces and then find out the limit?

Comment: The volume between the two planes is infinite. Could you check the equations of the surfaces?

Comment: @RobertZ    Sorry I missed out first octent. Could you tell me when do we take the region $D=\{f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)\} $ and when do we just take the projection of the surfaces on the $xy$ plane and figure out the $x,y$

Comment: Yes I do understand but in this case if we take $f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)$ we get $3x+y=6,x=0,y=0$ which gives me a different answer if we take $x+y=2,2x+y=4,x=0,y=0$. Where is the mistake?

Comment: I added a picture. Here also the surface $z=0$ is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

The first octant cut by the plane $x+y+2z=2$ is the tetrahedron
$$T_1=\{(x,y,z):x+y+2z\leq 2, x\geq 0, y\geq0, z\geq 0\}.$$
The first octant cut by the plane $2x+y+z=4$ is the tetrahedron
$$T_2=\{(x,y,z):2x+y+z\leq 4, x\geq 0, y\geq0, z\geq 0\}.$$
Notice that $T_1\subset T_2$: if $x+y+2z\leq 2$ and  $x,y,z\geq 0$ then
$$2x+y+z\leq 2(2-y-2z)+y+z=4-y-3z\leq 4.$$

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

Hence the desired volume is
$$\begin{align}\text{vol}(T_2)-\text{vol}(T_1)&=
\iint_{D_2}\Big(4-2x-y\Big)dxdy
-\iint_{D_1}\Big(1-\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)dxdy\\
&=\frac{16}{3}-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{14}{3}
\end{align}
$$
where
$$D_1=\{(x,y):x+y\leq 2, x\geq 0, y\geq0\}\;\text{and}\;
D_2=\{(x,y):2x+y\leq 4, x\geq 0, y\geq0\}.$$